# Javascript - Don't run code if the div is already displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have managed to come up with this javascript to slide down divs.

When clicked, it slides everything up, and then slides the one that was clicked.

The problem is when the same header is clicked when it was already open, causes the content to slide back up then back down again.

What is needed for the code to only slide back up if it is already displayed?

```
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var thelist = document.getElementsByClassName("alist");
        for (var i = 0; i < thelist.length; i++) {
              $(thelist[i]).slideUp( "slow", function() {});
        }

    //break if the DIV was displayed last!
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        $( e ).slideDown( "slow", function() {});
    }
```

Comment: you can use  $(element).is(':visible') and $(element).length > 0 to find if the div is present

Comment: Why so much mixed jQuery and plain JS when using jQuery can make this whole function into two lines (see my answer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test  the client width of the element to know if it's visible :

```
if (document.getElementById(id).clientHeight) return; // already visible
```

Or, as you seem to use jQuery :

```
if ($(e).is(':visible')) return;
```

Comment: @jfriend00 I supposed the element was invisible, due to the title of the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 no : if you set display:none, the element has a clientWidth of 0

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var thelist = document.getElementsByClassName("alist");
        for (var i = 0; i < thelist.length; i++) {
              $(thelist[i]).slideUp( "slow", function() {});
        }

    //break if the DIV was displayed last!
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.style.display != "none") {
            $( e ).slideDown( "slow", function() {});
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I initially thought this too but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the element passed to `toggle_visiblity` belongs to class `alist` . So the element you want to slide down, will first be slid up during the `for` loop, and then slid down again after  the loop. Add a check inside the loop, to check if the element is visible. If it is, only then slideup. What's happening here, is that your element is being slid up during the loop, since it is part of the list, and then again slid back down after the loop. Inside the loop, you want to slide up elements of `alist` that are not of type `id` .

Comment: Thank you that is what appears to be happening. I used some code from someone above to check if the DIV is shown, and if it is, then it will not scroll back down again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a lot simpler with all jQuery like this:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var newItem = $("#" + id).slideToggle("slow");
    $("[name='alist']").not(newItem).slideUp("slow");
}
```

This is very simple.  Toggle the passed in item and close any of the rest that were open.  Uses jQuery's `slideToggle()` to handle the toggle for you.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I just tried this, but only scrolls down the divs, and they do not scroll back up after.

Comment: @user3012826 - What do you mean scroll back up after?  If you want the clicked on item to toggle, then you can use `slideToggle()` instead on the clicked on item.  I've change my code to show that.

Answer (score 0):

It can be written much simpler:

```
 function toggle_visibility(id) {
     var $e = $(document.getElementById(id));
     if ($e.is(':visible')) return;

     $(".alist").slideUp("slow");
     $e.slideDown("slow");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. The "if ($e.is(':visible')) return;" line needs to be after the "$(".alist").slideUp("slow");" though. But it works nicely.